# How to convert my MEAN apllication to use mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I have been building a MEAN application. This is my first time using mongoDB and i'm struggling to be able to query my data how I want. I structured my application similar to how I would for SQL and I believe that is my downfall.

I use Node, Express, Mongoose and mongoDB. Would it be possible to easily transition and what wrapper for SQL should I use to best fit in with my current restfull structure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to work with Node.js, express and Angular, MEAN is okay. For MySQL, I suggest you use [sequelize Framework](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/).

> Sequelize is a promise-based ORM for Node.js and io.js. It supports
>   the dialects PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite and MSSQL and features
>   solid transaction support, relations, read replication and more.

In this case, you only need to modify the methods of persistence and query, such that you can learn with the docs and the stack overflow tags.